# HttpPost: InputDispatcher: "Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!" on Nexus 7

Tags: java, android, http-post, channel, socketchannel

On Nexus 7 (4.3), and not on my older device, LG Optimus 3d (Android 2.2), 
when I do HttpPost, I get this

E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '4273f7b0 ... MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

People have mentioned a possible memory leak. See **. However, this problem happens right away on startup when I try the HttpPost. Is it still likely a memory leak?

Here is how I'm doing the HttpPost:

```
public void server_addUserGetId()
{
    String url = GS.baseUrl() + "/users";
    HttpPost theHttpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dId", s_UserInfo.getInstance().m_device_id ));
    try {
        theHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpPostAsync theHttpPostAsync = new HttpPostAsync(new OnPostExecuteHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handlePostExecute(Object oHttpResponse) {
            HttpResponse theHttpResponse = (HttpResponse) oHttpResponse;
            JSONObject jo = GS.getJSONObject(theHttpResponse.getEntity());
            try {
                s_UserInfo.getInstance().m_user_id = jo.getString("_id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    theHttpPostAsync.execute(theHttpPost);
    return;
}
```

Here is my HttpPostAsync task:

```
public class HttpPostAsync extends AsyncTask<HttpPost, Integer, HttpResponse>
{
    private HttpPost m_HttpPost;
    private HttpResponse m_HttpResponse;

    private OnPostExecuteHandler m_OnPostExecuteHandler;
    public HttpPostAsync(OnPostExecuteHandler listener)
    {
        m_OnPostExecuteHandler = listener;
    }

    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(HttpPost ... args)
    {
        m_HttpPost = args[0];
        if(GS.dl>5) Log.d("GRA: HttpPostAsync", "doInBackground: Thread.currentThread().getId()=" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        m_HttpResponse = visit(m_HttpPost);
        return m_HttpResponse;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        if(GS.dl>5) Log.d("GRA: HttpPostAsync", "onPostExecute: Thread.currentThread().getId()=" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if(GS.dl>5) Log.d("GRA: HttpPostAsync", "onPostExecute: result=" + result);
        //if(GS.dl>5) Log.d("GRA: HttpPostAsync", "onPostExecute: m_HttpEntity="+m_HttpEntity);
        m_OnPostExecuteHandler.handlePostExecute(m_HttpResponse);
    }

    public HttpResponse visit(HttpPost theHttpPost)
    {
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            response = httpclient.execute(theHttpPost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("HttpPostAsync.java", "IOException e=" + e);
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

I read on an SO answer* it might have to do with the ArrayList initialization, so I've also tried initializing like this, with 1, in the ArrayList, but the problem persists:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
```

*: SO answer that didn't totally relate/help:
[App has stopped working Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509930/app-has-stopped-working-android)

** memory leak related? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the common issue of memory link due to some code.
Look at [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) in the developer docs to track it down.

Comment: This problem happens right away on startup when I try the HttpPost. Is it still likely a memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

**I met same troubles in 2 days ago for Android, not pure Java, this asnwer let you reference only.**
I solve it now.I am Taiwanese, I am glad to answer here once more.
Do you ever use UI new thread? Do not double use UI new thread look like sandwich. It should cause memory leaks.

**in a short sentence, a main thread could have many UI threads to do many work, but if one sub thread(not main thread) own a UI thread inside, maybe sub thread work done, but its kid ~ UI thread has not finish work, this will case memory leaks.**

**For example...for Fragment & UI application...this will cause memory leaks.**

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

    public void run() {

    ShowDataScreen();

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is error way",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }});// end of No.2 UI new thread

    }});// end of No.1 UI new thread
```

**My solution is rearrange as below:**

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
   public void run() {

    ShowDataScreen();

    }});// end of No.1 UI new thread        

getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
   public void run() {

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is correct way",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }});// end of No.2 UI new thread
```

for you reference.

Comment: Can't read your code, but wont gc collect instance of anonymous class regardless of its thread?